# When I bitlock non operating system drive, where does windows store the bitlocker password?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker

I enscrypt all of my computer hard drive.

To descrypt the drive, windows will need the private key. Where does windows store the private key of those drives?

On operating system drive?

Can I move those drive to different computer and get the data?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid security question. Why did it get downvoted...? (you have my upvote at least)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The private keys for these are stored with the operating system, and you need bit locker activated for the system drive as well.  if you move them to another computer you will have to use the bitlocker recovery key you would of hopefully saved to an external source as you will have to use bitlocker recovery to gain access again to the drive.

Comment: good answer for good question. Yet I got -1. I wonder why.,

Comment: Actually some says that as long as you know the password you can just move data drive to other computer and that would work.